# Loading WFS point layer with OpenLayers3?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

I am trying to get a point layer from GeoServer to load in my web app as a WFS. I can get a sample set of polygon data to load, but my points will not. Here is the code I am using for this:

```
var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    var url = 'http://........?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=Store:layer&' +
        'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures' +
        '&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
    $.ajax({url: url, dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: true});
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
    maxZoom: 19
  }))
});
window.loadFeatures = function(response) {
  vectorSource.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
};

var centerlocations = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
      width: 5
   })
  })
});
```

Is there something different that needs to be done for loading point data?

Comment: are there any points in response? if yes then check what readFeatures expects, else see Geoserver log file to see what went wrong

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, the points are coming up in response and everything seems to fit what readFeatures is expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style you have defined is not applied on points. For point you need to set an imageStyle like this:

```
new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
      width: 5
     }),
    radius: 5
  })
});
```